# Let $\Omega$ be the unit disk $|z|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be the unit disk $|z|<1$, skech the set $\Omega$ and $f(\Omega)\;$ for the function $f(z)=2z+3i$

Comment: try first with $g(z) = z+ \frac{3}{2}i$

Comment: @user1952009.. can you help me

Comment: @user1952009..can you expakin what is mean by the skech beetween them

Comment: Come on, work, make some drawings

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Proceed in steps. What happens to $\Omega$ when you dilate by $2$? When you translate by $3i$?

Comment: ...sorry i didn't get your idea can you explain me more please..thanks for your time

Comment: Think of $f$ as a composition of two functions, the first one being $f_1(z) = 2z$ and the second being $f_2(z) = z + 3i$. Can you tell me what each one does?

Comment: ,,  i am sorry but according your hint we can say that $f_2(f_1)z$ is our function

Comment: what expecting from like these functions are continuous are some what

Comment: ...can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: @AlfredYerger..you asking the translation of these functions

Comment: @suri That is right, that is what these functions are. But each one should be easy to describe if you draw a picture.